# Bind datagrdview combobox when manually added

Tags: c#, windows, datagridviewcombobox

Bind datagrdview combobox column when manually added in datagridview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code example demonstrates how to bind a collection of objects to a DataGridView control so that each object displays as a separate row. 
[How to: Bind Objects to Windows Forms DataGridView Controls](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y0wfd4yz.aspx)

[ComboBox with DataGridView in C#](https://khanrahim.wordpress.com/2010/04/13/combobox-with-datagridview-in-c/)